# Why Does My Tkinter Calculator Only Return Zero?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am fairly new to Tkinter and I'm trying to code a simple calculator. My problem is no matter what integers I provide the entry widget the sum always returns as zero. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried making the variables into global variables giving me the same result. I have also tried converting the entry from a StringVar() to int, but this results in a invalid literal error.

(ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '')

```
def addRes():
    ni1 = int(na1.get())
    ni2 = int(na2.get())
    result = ni1 + ni2
    resAdd = str(result)
    Radd = Tk()
    Radd.geometry("50x50")
    addL = Label(Radd, text= resAdd).pack()


nEadd = Tk()
nEadd.geometry("200x200")
na1 = IntVar()
na2 = IntVar()
numVal1 = Entry(nEadd).place(x=20,y=10)
plusL = Label(nEadd, text= "+").place(x=20,y=30)
numVal2 = Entry(nEadd).place(x=20,y=50) 
addResult = partial(addRes)
numSubmit = Button(nEadd, text= "Submit", command = addResult).place(x=40,y=70)
```

Comment: na1 and na2 are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you create two `IntVar`s, you don't associate them with an entry so they never change.

You need to change the entries to this:

```
numVal1 = Entry(nEadd, textvariable=na1).place(x=20,y=10)
numVal2 = Entry(nEadd, textvariable=na2).place(x=20,y=50)
```

Also, you should not be creating more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need another window, use `Toplevel`